# ACF Date Picker field convert to Age and populate field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Date Picker field in the backend which is used for people to select their Date of Birth, what I need is once the field has been filled out, is for another field to dynamically populate itself with the workings out of 'Current date - Selected date'.

The problem I'm having is with creating this field that will populate itself. Is it even possible using ACF? I've been through the docs of ACF and tried out their `update_field()` function but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to write your own JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the age as a value to display in your pages, you could just  make the calculation in your templates whenever you need the age, like this :

```
<?php 
    $date = get_field('date_of_birth');
    $birthday = new DateTime($date);
    $interval = $birthday->diff(new DateTime);
    echo $interval->y.' years old';
?>
```

Just make sure you have your acf date field set up to return a date format that `DateTime` understands, like `Ymd`.